# What web technology does Youtube use to create it's playlist bar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, ajax

www.youtube.com/disco, at the very bottom of the page is a cool playlist bar, does anyone know what technology it uses to create it? Or can anyone suggest a starting point for a newbie web developer to research? Thanks

Comment: sounds like homework. We don't do your homework, but we can help you if you've tried something and you're stuck.. So, what have you tried?

Comment: Why are people giving this negs? I want to recreate something similar to this but have no idea where to start. I was hoping that someone who looks at this notices similarity with something open source which I could look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter try following these links to get an understanding of the type of technology used to create the effect YouTube have on their playlist bar. I am not sure what they use to create the effect you want to emulate, but an understanding of some of the wizzy controls would be good for you. These links should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Try here and follow the tutorial if you are a complete novice:

[Basic jQuery Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)

Then you can look at some of the widget etc here:

[jQuery Widget, effects etc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

For things like the playlist you would need to use the api that YouTube provide and develop which would let you know when the video has been complete and then you could do a ajax call back to reload the video:

[jQuery Ajax Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

As an attempt to answer your question I think they use their own [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)